# text-weight troika-text (aframe, 8thwall)

Tags: javascript, aframe, 8thwall-xr

I would like to change font weight for troika-text package. I am currently coding on a-frame. My code does not seem to work.

troika-text could be found on github
https://github.com/lojjic/aframe-troika-text

This is the result I am aiming for, font weight 600:

[image]

This is the result I am getting, I understand this is normal weight 400

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<a-text
id="text"
position="0 0 -5"
troika-text="value: Hello World; align: center; color: white; font-size: 0.25; font-weight:    600"></a-text>
```

Comment: Also, your text value (if it has spaces in it) probably needs to be delimited by single apostrophes (i.e. `value: 'Hello World';`).

Comment: ^ Although the manual doesn't seem to think apostrophes are needed. But it also does not list weight as an available property.